# What defines a gui chow dish in Chinese cuisine?

Tags: restaurant-mimicry, chinese-cuisine

A restaurant near me makes a delicious dish they call Gui Chow Beef, which I want to reproduce. I've found some alternate spellings as "gui zhou" and even "aui zhau," but I've yet to find a recipe that represents what I've eaten.

The beef is thinly sliced and limp -- not battered or deep fried. I think there are bamboo shoots and celery. They use enough Szechuan peppercorns to numb my tongue; that's one of the most important ingredients to me. The sauce is dark and sour and there is always orange grease left on my plate when I'm done.

So. What am I eating, and how can I make it at home?

Answer (score 3):

Guizhou is a province in china. Sichuan is also a province and is much different food than guizhou food. Guizhou dishes are sour and hot where Sichuan are more spicy and garlicky. Just do a search for guizhou cuisine and you will find those dishes related to that culture.

http://community.travelchinaguide.com/forum2.asp?i=38624

再建!

Answer (score 1):

If the restaurant is run by Chinese people, the recipes will typically be family influenced. There is not a lot of real standard recipes in China due to it's size and cultural differences

It sounds like a typical western "Chinese" stir fry: vegetables and then thin sliced beef flash fried in some peanut oil (VERY hot wok), turn work down a bit, and sauce it up with a ladle of chicken stock, some corn starch, flavourings (salt, sesame oil, soy, sugar, even MSG?), and some roasted and powdered Szechuan pepper husks, short simmer and serve

Cooked Szechuan pepper generally makes that "sour" taste too. Try it with and without to see the difference

If you try a recipe search on "Szechuan pepper stir fry", and substitute in beef for whatever the recipe has, that should be close